# Git push rejected after adding Git support

Tags: git

After adding Git support, I'm not able to push to my repo.
I pulled as the error suggested, but it didn't work either.

How can I resolve this?

```
svelte-flow on  main [⇡] is  v0.2.4 via  v16.13.0 
❯ ggp                     
To github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

svelte-flow on  main [⇡] is  v0.2.4 via  v16.13.0 took 2s 
❯ gst
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

svelte-flow on  main [⇡] is  v0.2.4 via  v16.13.0 
❯ ggp
To github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

svelte-flow on  main [⇡] is  v0.2.4 via  v16.13.0 
❯ git pull                         
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 1.01 KiB | 172.00 KiB/s, done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
From github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow
   df125f9..381c351  main       -> origin/main
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.

svelte-flow on  main [⇕] is  v0.2.4 via  v16.13.0 took 2s 
❯ git pull origin main
From github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

Comment: Are `gst` and `gpp` aliases for Git commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have commits the remote branch does not have and the remote branch contains commits not in your local branch.

```
A-local
\
 - remote
```

Git protects you from overwriting the changes in the remote branch using the error you received.

Git allows to merge those changes but you didn't tell it what stretegy to use. It suggests you the following options when pulling:

#### merge

Merging branches means that you create a commit based of both commits (the local and remote one). This is the standard behaviour.

```
A - local   - merge commit
\          /
 - remote -
```

You can enable merging on pulls using `git config pull.rebase false`.

#### rebase

Rebasing means you are taking your local branch and putting it on top of the remote branch:

```
A - remote - local
```

You can enable rebasing on pulls using `git config pull.rebase true` or by pulling using `git pull --rebase`.

#### only allow fast forwards

You can also configure pulling in a way that it does not allow this case. If it would need to merge changes where both the local and remote branch have different commits, it would fail.

This can be configured using `git config pull.ff only`

Comment: After running git config pull.rebase false, I get this error. To github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:shinokada/svelte-flow.git' hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: You still need to pull (`git pull`).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. git pull, then git push.